# How to push data to JSON Object when push is considered un recognized

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

The function is there to distribute the JSON Array called cartItemObjectArray into the ComicIdArray, purchaseTypeArray, and quantityArray.

```
arraySetup(cartItemObjectArray) {
    var comicIdArray = [];
    var purchaseTypeArray = [];
    var quantityArray = [];

    for (let i in cartItemObjectArray) {
      comicIdArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("a_comic"));
      purchaseTypeArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("a_purchase"));
      quantityArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("a_quantity"));

      var comicId = cartItemObjectArray[i].comicid;
      var purchaseType = cartItemObjectArray[i].purchasetype;
      var quantityadded;

      if (comicIdArray == null) {
        comicIdArray.append(comicId);
        purchaseTypeArray.push(purchaseType);
        quantityArray.push(1);
        localStorage.setItem("a_comic", JSON.stringify(comicIdArray));
        localStorage.setItem("a_purchase", JSON.stringify(purchaseTypeArray));
        localStorage.setItem("a_quantity", JSON.stringify(quantityArray));
      } else {
        for (let index in cartItemObjectArray) {
          if (
            comicId == comicIdArray[index] &&
            purchaseType == purchaseTypeArray[index]
          ) {
            quantityadded = quantityArray[index];
            quantityArray[index] = quantityadded + 1;

            localStorage.setItem("a_quantity", JSON.stringify(quantityArray));
          } else {
            comicIdArray.push(comicId);
            purchaseTypeArray.push(purchaseType);
            quantityArray.push(1);

            localStorage.setItem("a_comic", JSON.stringify(comicIdArray));
            localStorage.setItem(
              "a_purchase",
              JSON.stringify(purchaseTypeArray)
            );
            localStorage.setItem("a_quantity", JSON.stringify(quantityArray));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This method is invoked by

```
this.arraySetup(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartitem")));
```

Inside the LocalStorage the cartItemObjectArray looks like this

```
[{comicid: "5f55e8f771b808206c132d7b", purchasetype: "pb_single"},…]
0: {comicid: "5f55e8f771b808206c132d7b", purchasetype: "pb_single"}
1: {comicid: "5f55e91271b808206c132d7c", purchasetype: "pb_single"}
```

Please , Im a beginner in React and Js, I really need your help.
Much Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do. first try to do it on paper then write code

Comment: im having the problem at the point... how to push data to json.object

Comment: What is the error message that you're seeing? Also, I suggest you minimize the amount of writing and accessing `localStorage` and just do it once at the end once you iterate through all your items.